# What should be done about animation media tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Should [animated-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animated-series) be retired? [animation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation)'s guidance is inconsistent with its use; it says that it should be on question about animation techniques, but [forty-five of the forty-six questions on it are mistagged](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation+story-identification) according to that (they use it as a media tag for story identification.)

Effectively, this makes [animation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) a media tag. So what should we do with it? I don't see why we should separate [animated-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animated-series), a tag for animated television of unknown style, from [animation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation), a potential tag for any sort of animation of unknown style, when we could just combine the two and add another tag, such as [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) or [movies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies), to show what format it was. What are the community's thoughts?

<sub>Note: this is an attempt at a better version of [this self-deleted question I wrote](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12412/animation-media-tags-make-no-sense).</sub>

Comment: What's bad about this question?

Comment: On meta, votes work differently. Downvotes signal disagreement, not that a question is bad. (I did not downvote, but I could understand why someone might disagree with this question's premise).

Comment: @Kevin what is wrong with the premise? (I don't understand, not saying my ideas are necessarily any good)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very late, but [animation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation)'s description now is:

> Use this tag on story-identification questions about works in unknown styles of animation in conjunction with another media tag such as [movie] or [short-film] when [animated-series] wouldn't make sense. Use [anime] or [cartoon] if the style of animation is known.